# "participants responses" or "participant responses" or "participants responses"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number, numbers

I have many participants, each will provide a response. Which of the following is the correct sentence to describe all the participants responses?

> We want to get the maximum number of:

`participants responses` or `participant responses` or `participants responses`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

> - We want to get the maximum number of participant responses.
> - We want to get the maximum number of participants' responses.

If there is any difference (I am not sure there is), the first might be emphasizing the responses a bit more, the second the participants. The first sounds a tiny bit more formal to me. But I think the two would be considered synonymous.